# Call WCF service with certificate authentication in ASP.NET Core without using transport security mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, certificate

I'm trying to use WCF certificate authentication in asp.net core web API but WCF client accepts a certificate in "transportwithmessagecredential" security mode that security mode is not supported in asp.net core. Let me know any other option to invoke certificate authentication in ASP.NET Core

Comment: TransportwithMessagecredential is not impletmented in Core. track the issue, https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/8 . we could use transport security mode as an 
 alternative.

Comment: But our client service they support "transportwithmessagecredtial". Any other way to send certificate in soap header from .Net core ? Please help on this issue.

Comment: what do you mean that your client service support "TransportwithMessagecredential"? would you mind sharing more details about the framework of the server and client? In my opinion, we could use Transport security mode to authenticate the client with a certificate, and it is supported by both Core and .netframework.